# Drupal 8 migrated fields in content type not showing in View module

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I used migrate module to convert my site from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.9.x. The content types and contents got migrated correctly. However when I try to create a view using a specific content type, I am unable to see the fields. Explaining the steps i followed:

1. Migrated content and content type from Drupal 7 to 8.9.x using
   migrate module
2. Example content type: funding fieldname: duedate
3. Created a view based on content type.
4. But after clicking "Add field" when searched for duedate, the field does not show up. in-fact any content type based field not showing up in the "Add field" dialog box
5. Same case with "Add filter" dialog box also.

Fix tried:

1. Went into funding content type and checked if the fields are enabled. Everything is enabled correctly
2. Checked text format and full text enabled correctly.

Any help on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same problem after migrating from drupal7 to drupal9. Text Fields using the format "Full HTML" did not show their contents in any display modes or views field output.
My solution was to temporarily allow the usage of Full HTML for anonymous users in /admin/config/content/formats. After seeing the field content I resetted the permissions of the editor format FULL HTML for security reasons (this time in /admin/people/permissions).
I suppose that the permission changes forced a permission correction.

Comment: Interesting. After setting that permission, were you able to see the fields in "Add field" dialog of view?

Comment: Yes, I always saw them in the field lists during content editing and view configuration, but not as an output on the page, in the views preview or in the block. At last the permission "changes" made the field contents "visible".